# Is this an AVL tree?

Tags: binary-search-tree, avl-tree

Is the following an AVL tree?

```
         10
   5            15
     7       12    17
       8
```

5-7-8 being the long branch

In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one. Is this satisfied here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not, because the subtrees of node 5 differ by more than 1 in height. The left subtree is empty (its height is 0) and the right subtree is 7-8 (so its height is 2).